# how do I install "waterfox-G4.0.6.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" on Ubuntu 22.04 ? I have seen no good answers to many very similar questions

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have downloaded "waterfox-G4.0.6.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" to my usual Downloads directory on a laptop that was running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  That machine has been upgraded with Ubuntu 20.04 and then 22.04.  So I still want to install the Waterfox G4.0.6 -- the package has not changed at all in the day or so it took me to make Ubuntu reasonably current.

I guess what puzzles me most is how a "package" can be just about anything according to some of the answers to similar questions (on this site) about installing Waterfox or other software all wrapped up as a .tar.bz2 file or something similar.

Practical solutions to installing "waterfox-G4.0.6.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" on Ubuntu 22.04 would be very helpful.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Terrance's answer seemed to come close, but when I open, click or double-click Waterfox in my Favorites lists, there is a lot of drive activity for a few seconds...then nothing further happens,   Since I have never actually run vG4.0.6 of Waterfox for Linux on any (presumably) compatible platform, I can only assume that it should work because there has been no mass griping to the contrary.

Comment: I need to verify each step and make sure I got it correct and that it seems to have done what it should.  That's a lot of new stuff for me to think about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the folder that you have downloaded `waterfox-G4.0.6.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2` do the following to extract the contents:

```
tar xvf waterfox-G4.0.6.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

Then enter the folder that was created

```
cd waterfox
```

Now create a folder that you are going to place Waterfox in:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/waterfox
```

and copy all the contents of the `waterfox` folder that you are in to the newly created folder

```
sudo cp -rav * /opt/waterfox/
```

After the files are copied, create a link to Waterfox in the `/usr/bin` folder so you can launch it command line

```
sudo ln -s /opt/waterfox/waterfox /usr/bin/waterfox
```

Now go to your local applications folder:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications/
```

and create a `Waterfox.desktop` file with the following contents in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Waterfox
Comment=Waterfox
Exec=/opt/waterfox/waterfox %u
Icon=/opt/waterfox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default64.png
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Application;Network;Security;
```

Make sure the permissions are correct to the file `chmod 644 Waterfox.desktop`

And now you should have Waterfox in your menu under Internet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You probably want to add `%u` to the command so one can configure for example html files to open with Waterfox

Comment: @vanadium Thanks for the suggestion!  I didn't think about that as I don't have any local files that I open and it has been working fine.  But there is always that one time I go to do it and it no workie!  =)

Comment: Creation of the .desktop file can be probably done via the GUI, using "add new application launcher" or something like this.

Comment: Add %u to which command exactly?  Also, could someone provide a link to the waterfox PPA. Thanks.

Comment: @MelvinQ.Watchpocket There isn't one.  There is only the one for Firefox that is for Ubuntu.  Waterfox is only installable as above.  The `%u` is added into my answer for the .desktop file.

Comment: Sorry about referring to Ubuntu 22.04.  I had exactly the same problem trying to install to 20.04, so an answer for that would be fine.  The main issue for me was not knowing exactly what needed to be done to convert the WF package to an installed executable program that operates about like FF95.  (I do realize that FF comes with Ubuntu whereas WF does not, so some differences are to be expected in the install process. :-)   TMG

Comment: @TMG The answer here is exactly how I have installed both Firefox and Waterfox directly from downloading the `tar.bz2` files.

Comment: Terrance, I will retry your procedure in a few hours.  It is easy to mistype things on this ancient laptop and I want to experiment with some alternative methods anyway -- learning a lot more about apt is a very high priority for me.

Comment: @TMG Normally I don't recommend doing it, but you can copy and paste my instructions into a terminal window for the commands to run.  There's nothing in my commands that is dangerous or destructive to a system.

Comment: There was a "u" parameter missing (as per someone's comment) and something about Security and Network seemed not defined sufficiently.  I can figure it out from here.  Thanks.

Comment: @TMG The `%u` is for when you need to assign the app to be like a default app when using a GUI file browser.  `.desktop` files are not used when doing a command line in a terminal window.  The Network and Security are Categories to help the app appear in the right location.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you!